# What does this interface syntax mean in python?

Tags: python, syntax, interface

I am doing [cs224n's assignment](https://github.com/JyiHUO/cs224n/blob/master/assignment1/q3_word2vec.py).In function `test_word2vec`, there is some python syntax I don not understand:

```
""" Interface to the dataset for negative sampling """
dataset = type('dummy', (), {})()
def dummySampleTokenIdx():
    return random.randint(0, 4)

def getRandomContext(C):
    tokens = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    return tokens[random.randint(0,4)], \
        [tokens[random.randint(0,4)] for i in xrange(2*C)]
dataset.sampleTokenIdx = dummySampleTokenIdx
dataset.getRandomContext = getRandomContext
```

Question one: What does `dataset = type('dummy', (), {})()` mean ?

Question two: In `dataset.sampleTokenIdx = dummySampleTokenIdx` , I do not think `dataset` has attribute `sampleTokenIdx` . So, why can dataset invoke it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function with 3 arguments creates a class.  So that would be equivalent to this code:

`class dummy(object):
    pass`

2. In Python you can add an attribute to an object at any time.  If it doesn't exist already, it will get created, essentially inserted into a dict that represents the object's attributes.